# How to properly use putAsync

Tags: node.js

I searched here and there and ended up with no finding regarding putAsync method of promisified request by bluebird.

```
var request = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.putAsync({
uri: buApiUrl,
headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
    name: BU,
    workstations: formattedWorkStaions[BU]
})
}).spread(function (response, body) {
debugHelper.log(body);
}).catch(function (err) {
debugHelper.error(err);
});
```

Above is the code snippet that is in my program. And it does not send put request. While using postAsync, if will send post request successfully.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand this words : ***And it does not send put request. While using postAsync, if will send post request successfully***

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me.

Example

```
var request = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.putAsync({
  uri: 'https://httpbin.org/put',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'anon'
  })
}).spread(function (response, body) {
  console.log(body);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

OR you can just pass JSON body like this -

```
request.putAsync({
  uri: 'https://httpbin.org/put',
  json: { name: 'anon' }
})
....
```

Make sure the API end-point is taking PUT requests and the variables `BU`,`formattedWorkStaions[BU]` are properly defined. I guess `formattedWorkStaions` should be `formattedWorkStations`?